# Spring integration gateway "Dispatcher has no subscribers"

Tags: spring-integration

I am getting an exception `Dispatcher has no subscribers` on the `outboundChannel` and can't figure out why. I am sure its something simple, I have stripped back my code to a very simple sample below:

My context is:

```
<bean id="requestService"
    class="com.sandpit.RequestService" />

<integration:channel id="inboundChannel" />

<integration:service-activator id="service"
    input-channel="inboundChannel"
    output-channel="outboundChannel"
    ref="requestService"
    method="handleRequest" />

<integration:channel id="outboundChannel" />

<integration:gateway id="gateway"
    service-interface="com.sandpit.Gateway"
    default-request-channel="inboundChannel"
    default-reply-channel="outboundChannel" />

<bean class="com.sandpit.GatewayTester">
    <property name="gateway"
        ref="gateway" />
</bean>
```

My Java code is:

```
public interface Gateway {

    String receive();
    void send(String message);
}

public class RequestService {

    public String handleRequest(String request) {

        return "Request received: " + request;
    }
}

public class GatewayTester implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    private Gateway gateway;

    public void setGateway(Gateway gateway) {

        this.gateway = gateway;
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {

        gateway.send("Hello world!");
        System.out.println("FROM SERVICE: " + gateway.receive());
    }
}
```

Note: A breakpoint does tell me that the `RequestService` is actually handling the request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`receive()` with no args needs the reply channel to be a `PollableChannel` See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway-calling-no-argument-methods).

add `<queue/>` to the `outboundChannel`.

Alternatively, You could change your gateway method to be `String sendAndReceive(String in)` and all will work as expected (and you can even remove the `outboundChannel` altogether).

Comment: Out of interest, my actual code has a transformer in the middle. I take it that this will mean I will still need the `outboundChannel` as the transforms are different going to and coming from the `RequestService`

Comment: Right - but the final consumer can simply omit an `output-channel` and it will go back to the gateway (when using request/reply). You generally only need a reply channel if you are using asynch (like you are), or if you want to log (or do something else with) the reply.

Comment: Thanks - this response answered another question I had.